# Vector bundle is semistable if only if it's pull back is semistable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

If $X$ is a smooth projective variety and $D$ is a divisor on $X$, and let $i:D\longrightarrow X$ be the closed immersion. Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Are there any theorems which say that $E$ is semi-stable if and only if $f^*E$ is semi-stable, subject to certain conditions? Any reference will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Semi-stability is defined with respect to a polarization on $X$. What is the relation of your $D$ with this polarization?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the following : $E$ is semi-stable with respect to the polarization $H$ if and only if $f*E$ is semi-stable with respect to $H|_D$.

Comment: Have you heard of Mehta-Ramanathan theorem? It tells you that your expectation is satisfied if $D\in |mH|$ is general, $m$ being large enough.

Comment: Doesn't it talk only about the restriction? That is, I thought it said that, if $E$ is semistable, then for a general $D$, $E|_D$ is semistable. Is the converse true too?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the theorem.

Comment: Simplest counterexample is $X = {\mathbb P}^2$, $D$ a line, $E = T_X$.

Comment: @Henri, Let $V$ be a semistable torsion free sheaf on $X$ (with respect to the
polarisation $H$). Let $Y_{(m)}$ be the generic curve of type (m). Then
there is an $m_o$ such that for $m\geq m_o$ the restriction of $V$ to $Y_m$ is semistable. I got this from mehta ramanathan paper. This seems to say one way only.

Comment: Thanks @Sasha, I want to know if additional conditions can be imposed so that this happens. Marayuma's paper looks like it suggests that.

Comment: @poorna The converse is obvious: any subsheaf $F$ of $E$ induces a subsheaf $F_{|D}$ of $E_{|D}$. And because $D\in |mH|$, the slope of $E_{|D}$ (resp. $F_{|D}$) is $m$ times the slope of $E$ (resp. $F$).